# Return int value from boolean field in SQL select

Tags: select

Is there a way to return an int value for a boolean field in a sql select statement?

Comment: Do you mean a "bit" field? SQL Server has no boolean. And can you give some more background please so we understand the context.

Answer (score 6):

```
declare @b bit = 1

select convert (int, @b)
```

or

```
select cast(@b as int)
```

[more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If that is really a boolean column, you can do this:

```
SELECT case 
          when boolean_value then 1
          else 0 
       end as boolean_as_integer
FROM your_table
```

that way you can also return other values than 1/0 if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not SQL Server. Maybe PostgreSQL?
Try this

```
create table booln1(a  boolean);
insert into booln1 values(true),(false);
select a, cast(a as int) as a1 from booln1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use CAST()

```
SELECT CAST(Bit_Column TO INT)
```

but it won't work in MySQL. For MySQL, you can use

```
SELECT IF(Bit_Column, 1, 0)
```